# How to customize JPA find query based on RequestFactorys's with() method

Tags: gwt, jpa, requestfactory

In my GWT 2.4.0 application I use RequestFactory and Hibernate/JPA. I have an entity `Agent` which has many `Administrators` through a `@OneToMany` relationship. This association is `LAZY` loaded. So when the find service is called the administrators of the agent are not loaded which is the desired behaviour in most cases.

However, I want to be able to indicate that I want the administrators of the agent back when firing a requestFactory request on the client side code by using the with method. So my client code would look something like:

```
RequestContext.findAgent(agentId).with("administrstors").fire()
```

and My server side service looks something like this:

```
public Agent findAgent(Long id) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT a" +
            " FROM Agent" +
            " WHERE a.id=:id", Agent.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

I want to be able to figure out if the with method was used to sent the request. I need to customize the JPA query to also load the admins of the agent in case with was used on client side. Is there a way to access the details of the request made through the RequestFactory on  server side?

If I know that the client code needs the admins of the agent tehn my JPA query would look like :

```
public Agent findAgent(Long id) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT a" +
            " FROM Agent a LEFT JOIN a.administrators admin" +
            " WHERE a.id=:id", Agent.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about the GWT part, but the JPA query is wrong. It should be select **distinct** a from Agent a left join **fetch** a.administrators admin where ...

Comment: @JBNizet: Right the DISTINCT keyword should be included. However you can drop the fetch.

Comment: No, you can't. Without the fetch, the administrators won't be loaded. If they were, fetch wouldn't have any utility.

Comment: I use LEFT JOIN without FETCH keyword in several places in my code and I get the collection back in my resultset. I searched in Hibernate documentation to find an explanation. Also looked at the JPA docs here : http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_Joins : An important use case for LEFT JOIN is in enabling the prefetching of related data items as a side effect of a query. This is accomplished by specifying the LEFT JOIN as a FETCH JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately impossible; you'll have to pass the information as additional arguments to the method in addition to the `with()`.

FYI, that was discussed 2 years ago in a Google Wave (I have a local backup copy, but it's otherwise nowhere to be found on the web), with several proposals (an optional `Set<String>` passed as the last argument to the service methods –your `findAgent` method–, or a thread-local list of properties).
Nothing like this has been implemented though, and in retrospect I'm not sure it should: passing the information explicitly as arguments to your method is more explicit / has less *magic* in it.